# How do I type this "Q" character?

Tags: symbols, type

I've seen the character in the image in some papers and books, but I've never been able to find a source for that. $\mathcal{Q}$ doesn't produce the exam symbol so I'm wondering if anyone knows how to type.

[image]

Comment: That's a rho, `\varrho`, not a Q.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it was a rho, that's why I couldn't find the command by googling.